# Pressed function key while upgrading pop_is to 21.04

Tags: linux, upgrade, pop-os

I accidentally pressed on (I think) one of the F9-F12 keys while upgrading to pop_os 21.04 at around 50% and then I got to this screen. After a while it kept showing this same message again and again and now its stuck saying "A start job is... 7s/no limit)" where 7 goes from 0 to 9.

What should I do?

[image: I can't really use screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment on this answer, you shouldn't turn off the PC during an OS upgrade, if you haven't already shut the machine down, try waiting a couple hours.

Otherwise;
full disclosure, there may be a more advanced/efficient way to troubleshoot & solve the issue, but I lack experience & this is a nice blanket solution. With that out of the way here it is:

If it's a UEFI installation of Pop!_OS:

1. Open the systemd-boot menu
   (For System76 hardware hold <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> while the PC starts, on non-System76 hardware, try the keys <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Boot into Pop!_OS recovery mode
3. Open the Pop!_OS installer
4. Choose "Refresh Install"
   (This *should* keep your files intact, but if you have the option to make a backup of any important data first, do it)

If it's a BIOS installation replace step 1 with the following:

1. Boot into GRUB by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while the PC starts

If there is no option to boot into recovery mode, you will need Pop!_OS installation media to boot into. It should be the same version you're currently running to use the "Refresh Install" feature. (e.g. a USB drive with the proper Pop!_OS image flashed onto it)

When all that is done, boot into Pop!_OS & try the upgrade again.
Once upgraded to 21.04 successfully, I recommend updating/upgrading system packages & the recovery partition image with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo pop-upgrade recovery upgrade from-release
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking time to write an answer! 
(Un)fortunately the system booted normally after an hour of waiting.
Also, it was in the middle of an OS upgrading, in which i don't think you're supposed to close or reset the system at all ^^'

Comment: Right, I don't know why I assumed you had already shut it down, added a warning at the top of the answer.